# Tensorflow Prediction in Bigquery Softmax

Tags: tensorflow, google-bigquery, softmax

I have a multiclass classification TensorFlow model imported into GCP BigQuery.  When you make predictions, the output is the probabilities which is a type FLOAT (the probabilities) and a mode REPEATED.  What is the best way to get the index of the max value using SQL in BigQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find an index of max value from an array, using an UDF would be handy, I think.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION index_of_max(probabilites ARRAY<FLOAT64>) AS ((
  SELECT i FROM UNNEST(probabilites) p WITH OFFSET i 
   WHERE p = (SELECT MAX(p) FROM UNNEST(probabilites) p)
));

SELECT index_of_max(dense_1) index_of_max FROM UNNEST([
  STRUCT([0.8611106872558594, 0.06648489832878113, 0.07240447402000427] AS dense_1),
  STRUCT([0.6251607537269592, 0.2989124655723572, 0.07592668384313583]),
  STRUCT([0.01427623350173235, 0.972910463809967, 0.01281337533146143])
]);
```

output:

[image]

[note] zero-based index

If applied to below example,

- https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/making-predictions-with-imported-tensorflow-models#making_predictions_with_imported_models

```sql
 SELECT dense_1, index_of_max(dense_1) AS index_of_max
   FROM ML.PREDICT (
          MODEL `testset_us.imported_tf_model`,
          (SELECT title AS input FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.stories`)
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

consider also slightly refactored version of proposed already UDF

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION index_of_max(probabilites ARRAY<FLOAT64>) AS ((
  SELECT i FROM UNNEST(probabilites) p WITH OFFSET i 
   ORDER BY p DESC LIMIT 1
));
```

OR

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION index_of_max(probabilites ARRAY<FLOAT64>) AS ((
  SELECT i FROM UNNEST(probabilites) p WITH OFFSET i 
  QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY p DESC)
));
```